# herokuデプロイ後にApplication Errorで表示が見えなくなりました。。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

https://sakuhin.herokuapp.com/static_pages/index　に
herokuにデプロイしたデータがエラーで表示されない状態になってしまいました。

その前に
helpers/application_helper.rb をうっかりコピーして
helpers/application_helper1.rb を作ってしまい
そのままデプロイして

herokuにcloud9で作ったapplication.cssをコンパイルしてアップしたら
Application Errorが出てしまいました。なのでhelpers/application_helper1.rbを削除して
またデプロイし直したのですがエラーが直らなくなってしまいました。

$heroku logsでログを見たら

```
2016-09-30T02:11:47.450536+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/static_pages/index" host=sakuhin.herokuapp.com request_id=134ebd15-ee8d-4e47-a39f-9d561730f0c9 fwd="157.14.181.116" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-09-30T02:11:48.187032+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=sakuhin.herokuapp.com request_id=8584a38c-2532-40f3-9ca5-739ef1bb7248 fwd="157.14.181.116" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-09-30T02:11:49.711261+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/static_pages/index" host=sakuhin.herokuapp.com request_id=85ec79c2-1c7a-400d-ad24-6bd5f19e3514 fwd="157.14.181.116" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-09-30T02:11:50.094256+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=sakuhin.herokuapp.com request_id=e3707328-9c6f-47f1-9986-fd1962a3d44e fwd="157.14.181.116" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

にエラーが出ているようなのですが
どこを修正していいかよくわからない状態です。

```
 $ git status
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        deleted:    app/helpers/application1_helper.rb

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

では削除したapplication1_helper.rb
が問題になっているようなのです。

ご教示の程、何卒宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: 自己解決した場合は、自己回答し、その回答を承認してくださるとありがたいです

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/49815

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$ git status  
で(use "git add/rm ..." to update what will be committed)  
とあったため

$ git rm app/helpers/application1_helper.rb のコマンド 
で誤って作ったデータを消したら見えるようになりました。 
お騒がせ致しました。

下記記事等なども参考に合わせてみました。 
https://git-scm.com/book/ja/v1/Git-%E3%81%AE%E5%9F%BA%E6%9C%AC-%E5%A4%89%E6%9B%B4%E5%86%85%E5%AE%B9%E3%81%AE%E3%83%AA%E3%83%9D%E3%82%B8%E3%83%88%E3%83%AA%E3%81%B8%E3%81%AE%E8%A8%98%E9%8C%B2

http://kray.jp/blog/git-why-explanation/